# what are all the web application present which is similar to jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am looking for some web application which is similar to jquery is there any

Comment: jQuery !== web application. You may want to rephrase that question, I don't know what you mean.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery is not a web application. It's a compact javascript library with lots of regularly used functions and properties to make JavaScript development easier.

Here are some [alternatives](http://javascriptlibraries.com/) you may be interested in:

- [MooTools](http://mootools.net/)
- [ProtoType](http://www.prototypejs.org/)
- [Glow](http://www.bbc.co.uk/glow/)
- [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/)
- [Dojo](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/)

Answer (score 2):

you may use moo too ,,,,http://www.monkeyphysics.com 
     yui is another userfull we application download yui1.3.2 and use

Answer (score 2):

First of all jquery is not a web application, its a javascript library.

If you are looking for other javascript libraries then

[**Prototype**](http://www.prototypejs.org/), [**Mootools**](http://mootools.net/), **[ExtJS](http://www.extjs.com/)**, [**Dojo**](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/), [**YUI**](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/)

all will be helpful.

Here is a [**complete listing of javascript libraries**](http://javascriptlibraries.com/)

Answer (score 0):

There is another framework called [prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) is similar to JQuery. There are others like [MooTools](http://mootools.net/), [GLOW](http://www.bbc.co.uk/glow/) and [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/). You can check details. [Here.](http://www.prototypejs.org/) JQuery and prototype are not web applications but JS frameworks. Why do you actually want an alternative?